# Как обратиться к полям Entry, созданным в цикле

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Я с помощью цикла создаю таблицу из полей ввода. Пользователь должен ввести туда какие-либо числа, а программ должна найти максимальное значение. Как можно получить данные из всех полей ввода и добавить все эти значения в список?

```
    for i in range(x):
        for b in range(y):
            self.entry = Tk.Entry(parent, width=4, font=("Helvetica", 12)).grid(row=b, column=i)
```

Comment: а в чем смысл в `self.entry = `? зачем вам после помнить последний Entry? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом: создать пустой список, и заполнить его соответствующими объектами:

```
entries = [] # создаём пустой список
for i in range(x):
    for b in range(y):
        entry = Tk.Entry(parent, width=4, font=("Helvetica", 12))
        entries.append(entry) # добавляем объект entry в список
        entry.grid(row=b, column=i) # располагаем объект в родительском окне
```

Также важно выполнять метод `grid` в последнюю очередь, т.к. он возвращает `NoneType` и вместо объектов типа `Tk.Entry` массив будет заполнен `None`.

Получаем список значений:

```
items = [e.get() for e in entries]
```

Вариант с двумерным списком:

```
entries = [] # создаём пустой список
for i in range(x):
    e = []
    for b in range(y):
        entry = Tk.Entry(parent, width=4, font=("Helvetica", 12))
        e.append(entry) # добавляем объект entry в список
        entry.grid(row=b, column=i) # располагаем объект в родительском окне
    entries.append(e)
```

Comment: Опередили, но у вас правильнее -- насчет `.grid(` забыл :) Кст, можно добавить `items = [e.get() for e in self.entries]` -- это насчет списка значений

Comment: Я так понимаю, там двумерная таблица, и список скорее всего нужен двумерный.

Comment: Да вот буквально недавно сталкивался с подобной проблемой, `grid` и `place` возвращают `None`

Comment: Выдает ошибку:
items = [self.e.get() for self.e in self.entries]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @Hasegawa потому что должно быть `[e.get() for e in self.entries]`, не нужно вставлять `self` везде.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно воспользоваться функцией `grid_slaves()` (если у вас только `Entry` во фрейме) и путем отсортировки просто показать максимальное число

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root)

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        tk.Entry(frame, width=4, font=("Helvetica", 12)).grid(row=j, column=i)

frame.pack()
b = tk.Button(root, text="Press", command=lambda: print(max([int(b.get()) for b in frame.grid_slaves()]))).pack()
root.mainloop()
```